# how to speed up the SQL query speed

Tags: mysql, database, performance, time-series

I store all equity transaction of every trading day into the table. The table contain millions of rows. Since at the same time and second, there could be 2 or more transaction happening, and the source data do not have any primary key either. so I didn't add any primary key to the table. But doing any query is very slow, about 60 - 120secs.

Here's the structure: mysql, innodb, utf8_general_ci

```
Ticker varchar(15)
ReleaseDT datetime
Order int(1)
Price decimal (7,3)
Volume bigint(13)
Amount bigint(13)
NoOfLot int(11)
Session varchar(3)
Source varchar(15)
TimeStamp timestamp
```

function:

1. get each ticker volume by price per day or throughout a period of time.
2. to see how many total buy and total sell of a ticker each day
3. further on point 2, i will divide it into morning total buy and morning total sell.

Question:
 1. As there is no unique item that I could find, will no primary key for this table affect the query speed?

2. Shall I just add an auto_incremental # like ID, and it creates itself? does it help for query speed?
3. Some query it takes me 60-120secs, any way to improve the above table? like index? if yes, please advise how.

I will use php for web query and output and sometimes vb.net to query from mysql server.

example:

```
 select Ticker, ReleaseDT as 'Last Update',Price, convert(sum(case when iOrder = 1 then Amount else 0 end ),decimal(9,0)) as TtlBuyAmt,
 convert(sum(case when iOrder = -1 then Amount else 0 end ),decimal(9,0)) as TTlSellAmt,
 convert(sum(case when iOrder = 0 then Amount else 0 end ),decimal(9,0)) as TTlUndetAmt,
 convert(sum(case when iOrder = 1 then Amount else 0 end ) / sum(case when iOrder = -1 then Amount else 0 end),decimal(9,0)) as TTlBuySellRatio,
 sum(case when iOrder = 1 and Session = 'AM' then Amount else 0 end ) as BuyAmtAM ,
 SUM(CASE WHEN iOrder = 1 and Session = 'PM' then Amount else 0 end ) as BuyAmtPM ,
 SUM(CASE WHEN iOrder = -1 and Session = 'AM' then Amount else 0 end) as SellAmtAM,
 SUM(CASE WHEN iOrder = -1 and Session = 'PM' then Amount else 0 end ) as SellAmtPM ,
 convert(SUM(CASE WHEN iOrder = -1 and Session = 'PM' then Amount else 0 end ) / SUM(CASE WHEN iOrder = -1 and Session = 'AM' then Amount else 0 end),decimal(5,2)) as SellPMAMRatio,
 sum(Amount) as TotalAmt,
 convert(sum(case when iOrder = 1 then Amount else 0 end ) - sum(case when iOrder = -1 then Amount else 0 end ),decimal(9,0)) as NetAmount
 FROM Trade
 WHERE Ticker = '1 HK EQUITY' and DATE(ReleaseDT) between '20150102' and '20150104'
 GROUP BY Ticker, date(ReleaseDT), Price
 ORDER BY Ticker ASC, Price DESC
```

This takes >60secs to run, any way to improve?

```
SELECT * FROM AS2046.BlockTrade_EOD where Ticker = '1 HK EQUITY' and Date(ReleaseDT) > '20150102' Group by Price
```

using EXPLAIN... and results as follows:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'BlockTrade_EOD', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2327212', 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'
```

Comment: Please do an `EXPLAIN SELECT [...]` with your query and post the result in your question. Also please post the full `CREATE TABLE `-statement from the tables involved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is no doubt that indexes will help your queries on this table. For us to help you, we need to see some of the queries that are slow. Please edit your question to include them. In the meantime, read about **compound covering indexes,.**

Comment: added. This is one of the commonly used sql query.

Comment: why down vote? It's not just indexing problem. It's as a whole to see whether adding primary key (auto incremental), or add index, or anything else to improve the peformance when we face the situation that seems no meaningful unique primary key is avaiable.

Answer (score 1):

A unique, auto-incremented primary key is useful for many reasons -- such as when you want to update or delete data.  However, if you have no foreign key relationships it is not strictly necessary.

For your query, a composite index should help:

```
create index idx_Trade_ReleaseDT on Trade(Ticker, ReleaseDT)
```

However, you need to fix the `where` clause.  If `ReleaseDt` has no time component, then use:

```
WHERE Ticker = '1 HK EQUITY' and
      ReleaseDT between DATE('2015-01-02') and DATE('2015-01-04')
```

Or, if `ReleaseDT` could have a time component:

```
WHERE Ticker = '1 HK EQUITY' and
      ReleaseDT >= DATE('2015-01-02') and
      ReleaseDT < DATE('2015-01-05')
```

Comment: Thanks first. I got lost connection during create index.
Besides, I have use Date(ReleaseDT) between '20150102' and '20150104' which shall serve same purpose as you suggest.

Comment: @Trader . . . I don't think that construct will use the index.  You generally need "bare" columns for the engine to take advantage of an index.

Answer (score 0):

since this is still a rather broad question with very limited input, I will try to give some limited advice:

1. A primary key will not necessarily speed up queries. It largely depends of the kind of your queries. Oftentimes Indexes (not necessarily Primary keys) From the query you posted, there seems to be the possibility, that an index on Ticker (not a primary key, since Ticker is not unique, as it seems) could possibly speed up operations ("WHERE Tickler = '...'"). Also the ReleaseDT is a candidate for an index -- possibly together with Ticker. But all this depends on the data in your table ... for example: How many of the rows have the Ticker value "1 HK EQUITY".
2. Very unlikely will adding an artificial PK speed up operations. Many databases add an artificial PK by themselves. Also I don't see how an artificial PK could help for this select. Of course, a primary key could be useful in other selects.
3. See 1. My best guess would be Ticker and/or ReleaseDT for an index (or even PK, depending on your data). What you see is most likely a "full table scan" -- the database engine has to process all your million rows for one SELECT. An index could dramatically reduce operations -- depending on your data in the database.

I would recommend checking the contents of your table (for example how many rows contain "1 HK EQUITY" as Ticker. If only a fraction of rows do so, start adding an index on this row.

But: Beware -- every index on a table will add complexity for all writes to the table, since the index must be maintained.

For further advice, more data would be needed!

Answer (score 0):

First, should ReleaseDT be DATETIME, not just DATE?  Assuming there is a TIME component...

If the table is InnoDB, you *really* should have an explicit PRIMARY KEY.  (If it is MyISAM, it does not matter.  (Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE)

Add the compound index `INDEX(Ticker, ReleaseDT)`.  *AND* do not hide columns inside functions, such as `DATE(ReleaseDT)`.  That makes it impossible to use the index.  As @Gordon says, but even simpler:

```
ReleaseDT >= '2015-01-02' and
ReleaseDT <  '2015-01-05'
```

I prefer this if I know how many days and don't want to play date arithmetic:

```
ReleaseDT >= '2015-01-02' and
ReleaseDT <  '2015-01-02' + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

No change is needed to

```
GROUP BY Ticker, date(ReleaseDT), Price
```

Perhaps

```
convert(sum(case when iOrder = -1 then Amount else 0 end ),decimal(9,0))
```

can be simplified to

```
SUM(IF(iOrder = -1, Amount, 0))
```

If ReleaseDT can be DATE, then PRIMARY KEY(Ticker, ReleaseDT) is probably better.